# AdWhirl not requesting ads

Tags: android, admob, adwhirl

I've been using AdWhirl for about four days now and it seems to have stopped requesting ads to other Ad networks.  The first few days I was getting ads from AdMob.  Recently, however I have had over 4000 requests and all of them are going strait to house ads.  My allocation is 95% AdMob and 5% House ads, and my back fill is AdMob then House Ads.  Looking at my AdMob account, it has not received any requests for Ads.

I've double checked my AdMob ID - I don't know if this is an AdWhirl issue or a coding issue (I have not changed the source code - Android is the target device).

Thank you.

I wanted to add that It seems to be working fine on the emulator (getting ads), but on my phone and a friends phone there seem to be no Ads except for house ads.